# TreeMap with comparator comparing length of string in keys

Tags: java, treemap

I need a TreeMap mapping Strings to Integers using the length of the string as the sorting criteria. This is my code:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)) {{
  put("one", 1);
  put("two", 2);
  put("three", 3);
  put("four", 4);
  put("five", 5);
  put("six", 6);
}};
```

I expect the content of the map to be something like this:

```
{one=1, two=2, six=6, four=4, five=5, three=3}
```

but what I get instead is:

```
{one=6, four=5, three=3}
```

Looking at the code of the `put` method of the TreeMap, I can see that if a Comparator has been defined, then it uses the value returned by the comparator to decide if to create a new key in the map, or to overwrite the value of an existing one. In my case, since I have three keys of length 3 ("one", "two" and "six"), it inserts only one key of length 3 (the first inserted, "one") and updates its value (first 1, then 2 and at last 6). The same goes for key of length 4 ("four" and "five").

How can I have the tree map inserting all the keys I defined ("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six") sorted by the length of the key?

Comment: The output makes it obvious that only the first key with unique length is kept. If the lengths are the same, you’ll want to compare the keys naturally in order to get the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specified order `{one=1, two=2, six=6, four=4, five=5, three=3}` cannot be achieved with the `TreeMap` because this implementation can be sorted only by keys, and as soon as the lengths of the keys have multiple collisions, additional comparator *for the value* is needed.

Thus, a raw map may be created first, then its `entrySet` can be sorted in a custom order using Stream API `Stream::sorted` and `Collectors.toMap`:

1. by key length (ascending)
2. by value (ascending)

Then the result is collected into a `LinkedHashMap` famous for maintaining the insertion order:

```java
Map<String, Integer> raw = new HashMap<>() {{
  put("one", 1);
  put("two", 2);
  put("three", 3);
  put("four", 4);
  put("five", 5);
  put("six", 6);
}};

Map<String, Integer> map = raw.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>comparingInt(e -> e.getKey().length())
        .thenComparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a, b) -> a,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{one=1, two=2, six=6, four=4, five=5, three=3}
```

---

**Update**

It appears that for the given input a custom comparator may be provided for the `TreeMap` maintaining the insertion order:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new TreeMap<>(
    Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
        .thenComparing((k1, k2) -> 1) // pick the "earlier" key of the two
) {{
  put("one", 1);
  put("two", 2);
  put("three", 3);
  put("four", 4);
  put("five", 5);
  put("six", 6);
}};
System.out.println(map2);
```

Output:

```
{one=1, two=2, six=6, four=4, five=5, three=3}
```

Comment: using 1 (or -1) for ordering the keys with the same length is really clever, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a double comparator, where you first compare the string lengths, then the strings themselves. Like:

```
public class MyTreeMapComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String one, String two) {
    if (one.length() == two.length()) {
      return one.compareTo(two);
    } else return two.length() - one.length();
  }
}
```